# How to specify a similiarities options checker of pylint in pre-commit args?

Tags: similarity, pylint, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I've been trying to configure my pre-commit config file to ignore similiarities on imports and docstrings as described in: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html?highlight=similar#similarities-checker-options

But I don't use any of .pylintrc files, just the .pre-commit-config.yaml.
Below is a snippet from `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```
-   id: pylint
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: python
        require_serial: true
        types_or: [python, pyi]
        exclude: 'kedro-init'
        args: ['--disable=E0401,E1101,E1102,R0913,R0914,W0703,E0602,C0103,C0114,
        W0102,C0330,C0326,W0107,R1716,R0902,E0611,E1124', '--fail-under=7.5',
        '--ignore-imports=yes', '--ignore-docstrings=yes'] #this last line does not work
```

Is there any way to specify those options on the `args` key?

Thx!
python version: 3.8.x
pylint version: 2.12.3

Comment: pylint also has a ``--long-help`` option where the option is documented in 2.13.3. Is there an error saying that no such argument exists if you add gibberish to the option ? Are you sure that what is around docstrings and imports is not duplicated too ?

Answer (score 0):

If you retype your `args` in `.pre-commit-config.yaml` as below, it should work.

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: pylint
      name: pylint
      entry: pylint
      language: python
      require_serial: true
      types_or: [python, pyi]
      exclude: 'kedro-init'
      args: ["--ignore=E0401,E1101,E1102,R0913,R0914,W0703,E0602,C0103, 
      C0114, W0102,C0330,C0326,W0107,R1716,R0902,E0611,E1124", 
      "--fail-under=7.5"]
```